# Django server-sent events in 2016

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to set up a multi user edit session, using server-sent events to warn the user that someone else is also editing that object (like in google docs)

```
class Edit_Session(models.Model):
    #uuid is a global unique field for all models
    object_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So all I need is to send a message to the client if there is someone else editing the same uuid as him.

I've read about websockets, tornado, twisted and all that, but is there a simpler way to achieve this in Django that doesn't involve having to learn another library and figure out how to integrate them with Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Is there another way to do this... without learning another library
>   and integrate it with Django?"

Short answer, not yet.

**Longer answer:**
The correct way to do this in Django will be to [use Django-Channels](https://github.com/django/channels), which uses websockets.  Channels has been adopted [as an official Django Project](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2016/sep/09/channels-adopted-official-django-project/), and will be supported (and maybe integrated at some point) over the next few releases.

There is a great list of example project available from [Andrew Godwin's github.](https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples)

Yes, it's another library, but it's as close to batteries-included-django as you'll get for doing this kind of work.